# Law of Total Expectation and Joint PDF's

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

> Jim, a part of the maintenance department at a local swimming pool, is responsible for making sure the pool always has enough water for patrons to swim comfortably. As they move to and from the pool, water is slowly removed through splashing.
>
> He decides try and model the amount of water he uses per hour when topping up the pool. He assumes that the number of people using the swimming pool follows a Poisson distribution with mean $\lambda$, and the amount of water a patron displaces from the pool while they're swimming follows a Normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.
>
> 1) Show that the average amount of water used by Jim is $\mu \lambda$.
>
> (Customers displace water independently)

I'm stumped with this question, however, I feel like it has something to do with the law of total expectation.

---

My working so far,

Let $X(t)$ be the number of people using the swimming pool per hour $X(t)\sim Pois(\lambda)$.

Let $Y$ be the amount of water displaced from the pool by a given patron $Y \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

My next thought was to multiply their respective pdf's to obtain a joint pdf (since the question says water usage is independent).

$$p(x,y) = \frac{1}{{\sigma \sqrt {2\pi }}}e^{\frac{(x - \mu)^2}{2\sigma ^2}}\cdot\frac{{e^{ - \lambda } \lambda ^x }}{{x!}}$$

However, I feel like this is way too messy to integrate. Beyond here I'm not really sure what to do next.

Comment: You've already made a mistake: you are summing up $X$ iid $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ r.v.s $Y_n$ where $X \sim Pois(\lambda)$ is independent of all the $Y_n$. That is, you don't have just one $Y$. Now set up the total expectation formula for conditioning against each value of $X$.

Comment: I do not even want to think about the positive probability that some customers add water to the pool

Comment: @Henry That's a routine issue in Gaussian approximation of most meaningful phenomena. Though actually the Gaussian assumption was totally unnecessary in this case (maybe they need it later in the problem).

Comment: @Ian I'm not completely sure I follow, sorry! Would you be able to elaborate a little more?

Comment: I believe Henry was making a joke that some people piss in the pool

Comment: Let's say $N$ is Poisson($\lambda$) distributed and $W$ is our desired random variable. You have $E[W]=\sum_{k=0}^\infty E[W \mid N=k] P[N=k]$; this is the total expectation formula.

Comment: @manofbear I get the joke, but I think the joke was also related to this issue of Gaussian approximations to quantities which in reality are guaranteed to have one sign or the other (like the amount of water splashed out of a pool).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a sequence, ${\{Y_k\}}_{k\in\{1..N\}}$, of $N$ independent and identically normally distributed random variables, where $N$ is Poisson distributed (and each $Y_k$ is also independent of that $N$).

Use the Law of Total Expectation, the Linearity of Expectation, the Identical Distributions of the sequence, and the Independence of the random variables to express $\mathsf E(\sum_{k=1}^N Y_k)$ in terms of $\mathsf E(N)$ and $\mathsf E(Y_1)$; that is $\lambda$ and $\mu$ respectively.

> $\mathsf E(\sum_{k=1}^N Y_k)~{=~\mathsf E(\mathsf E(\sum_{k=1}^N Y_k\mid N)) \qquad\text{Total Expectation} \\=~ \mathsf E(\sum_{k=1}^N~\mathsf E(Y_k\mid N))\qquad\text{Linearity of Expectation}\\ =~\mathsf E(N)~\mathsf E(Y_1)\qquad\qquad\quad\;\text{Independence and Identicality}}$

---

PS: You may also find $\mathsf {Var}(\sum_{k=1}^N Y_k)$ in a similar manner.